# Is there a better approach than repeat all the statments for every cfnumGrantAmount property using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am repeating the following statements for each Year Amount(e.g cfnumGrantAmountY1,cfnumGrantAmountY2,cfnumGrantAmountY3,cfnumGrantAmountY4) and adding them to the globalScholarsL3Data array if they exist in the validScholars object.
Can the following code be improved instead of repeating the following statements for each year:

```html
const  globalScholarsL3Data = [];
const  globalFiscalYear = "2019";
const validScholars = [
  {
  "recordid": "11085716",
  "sfParentID": "8633154",
  "cfScholarshipAwardforAcademicYear": "21000",
  "sfStatusID": "50298",
  "cfScholarPhone": "315-263-7593",
  "sfTypeID": "49613",
  "cftxtIntendedProfession": "",        
  "cfnumGrantAmountY1": "100",
   "cfnumGrantAmountY2": "101",
   "cfnumGrantAmountY3": "102",
   "cfnumGrantAmountY4": "103"
  },
  {
  "recordid": "11085717",
  "sfParentID": "8633154",
  "cfScholarshipAwardforAcademicYear": "21000",
  "sfStatusID": "50298",
  "cfScholarPhone": "315-263-7593",
  "sfTypeID": "49613",
  "cftxtIntendedProfession": "",       
  "cfnumGrantAmountY1": "1",
  "cfnumGrantAmountY2": "2",
  "cfnumGrantAmountY3": "",
  "cfnumGrantAmountY4": "4"
  }
]

validScholars.forEach(item => {
                  const TempArrayData = [];
                  if(!!item["cfnumGrantAmountY1"] || !!item["cfnumGrantAmountY2"] || !!item["cfnumGrantAmountY3"] || !!item["cfnumGrantAmountY4"]) {
                    
                    if(!!item["cfnumGrantAmountY1"]) {
                      TempArrayData.push({
                        "recordid":"0",
                        "objectid":"0",
                        "sf_Parent ID":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Type ID":"50300",       
                        "sf_Level Three ID":"0",
                        "sf_Status ID":"49415",
                        "cf_1538386":!!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear : "",
                        "cf_1538387":item["cfnumGrantAmountY1"],
                      });
                    }

                    if(!!item["cfnumGrantAmountY2"]) {
                      TempArrayData.push({
                        "recordid":"0",
                        "objectid":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Parent ID":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Type ID":"50300",       
                        "sf_Level Three ID":"0",
                        "sf_Status ID":"49415",
                        "cf_1538386":!!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear + 1 : "",
                        "cf_1538387":item["cfnumGrantAmountY2"],
                      });
                    }

                    if(!!item["cfnumGrantAmountY3"]) {
                      TempArrayData.push({
                        "recordid":"0",
                        "objectid":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Parent ID":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Type ID":"50300",       
                        "sf_Level Three ID":"0",
                        "sf_Status ID":"49415",
                        "cf_1538386":!!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear + 2 : "",
                        "cf_1538387":item["cfnumGrantAmountY3"],
                      });
                    }

                    if(!!item["cfnumGrantAmountY4"]) {
                      TempArrayData.push({
                        "recordid":"0",
                        "objectid":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Parent ID":item["recordid"],
                        "sf_Type ID":"50300",       
                        "sf_Level Three ID":"0",
                        "sf_Status ID":"49415",
                        "cf_1538386":!!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear + 3 : "",
                        "cf_1538387":item["cfnumGrantAmountY4"],
                      });
                    }                    
                  }       

                  TempArrayData.length && globalScholarsL3Data.push(...TempArrayData);
                })
                console.log('globalScholarsL3Data', globalScholarsL3Data);
                ----------------
//Intended globalScholarsL3Data 
    globalScholarsL3Data =          [
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085716",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085716",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2019,
    "cf_1538387": "100"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085716",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085716",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2020,
    "cf_1538387": "101"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085716",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085716",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2021,
    "cf_1538387": "102"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085716",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085716",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2022,
    "cf_1538387": "103"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "0",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085717",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2019,
    "cf_1538387": "1"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085717",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085717",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2020,
    "cf_1538387": "2"
  },
  {
    "recordid": "0",
    "objectid": "11085717",
    "sf_Parent ID": "11085717",
    "sf_Type ID": "50300",
    "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
    "sf_Status ID": "49415",
    "cf_1538386": 2022,
    "cf_1538387": "4"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bracket notation with an expression inside a for loop:

```js
validScholars.forEach(item => {
    const TempArrayData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= validScholars; i++) {
        const strPropName = `cfnumGrantAmountY${i}`;
        let objId = item["recordid"];
        let cf_1538386 = !!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear + i : "";
        if (i === 1) {
            objId = "0";
            cf_1538386 = !!globalFiscalYear ? +globalFiscalYear : "";
        }
        TempArrayData.push({
            "recordid": "0",
            "objectid": objId,
            "sf_Parent ID": item["recordid"],
            "sf_Type ID": "50300",       
            "sf_Level Three ID": "0",
            "sf_Status ID": "49415",
            "cf_1538386": cf_1538386,
            "cf_1538387": item[strPropName],
        });
        TempArrayData.length && globalScholarsL3Data.push(...TempArrayData);
    }
});

console.log('globalScholarsL3Data', globalScholarsL3Data);
```

Comment: const objId is constant and you are assigning value as well(objId = "0";).

Comment: Replace const with let @KarimAli

Comment: Doesn't work with let as well.

Comment: Please tell me what does not work. Is it a Javascript error?

Comment: It is not giving me Intended globalScholarsL3Data with 7 objects.